# Confusion of limit when doing in two ways.

Tags: calculus, limits

https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/u43127h1274925p6680268

This limit question is an eye opener for me.where is the problem in attachment .guide

Comment: @BarryCipra: How did you find that duplicate!? :)

Comment: Nice example. Giving a non-existent object a name and doing manipulations on the name does not produce existence. The most you can conclude is that if the limit existed it would  be $\dots$.

Comment: @H.R., I gave an answer to it.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Ah! :D I see!

Comment: The post pretty much explains it all. The function $\frac{a^x -  x -  1}{x^2}$ blows up to positive infinity to the right of 0 and goes to negative infinity to the left of 0, except at the one exceptional case where $a=e$,  aka Eulers Number. In this case the function is continuous at 0, and the limit yields $\frac 12$. If you want a good explanation of this look at the Laurent series for the function...  I won't do this for you until you show more work though.

Comment: Is there any other simple example  which can behave in a same way.